# Cannot find the correct root for cake console

Tags: cakephp

I've trying to get the CakePHP console running, reading and watching as many tutorials as I can find but to no avail. I got the latest realese of Cake from their Git, 3.08 in this case, because the composer instalation wasn't working I had to manually configure everyhing and so far so good.

The problem is that I cannot for the life of me find the cake console, much of the tutorial I find make reference to a lib, app or console folder.

[image: This is my current cake folder, at C:\wamp\www\cake]

The only thing that resembles what I've seen in tutorial is on the bin folder, where a cake.php, cake.bat and cake file reside, there is no console folder there though, no exceptions etc, using the file finder for console turns out like 10 result but none with the cake.bat and these other files together.

[image: bin folder]

[image: cake/vendor]

I know this must be a very dumb question but what I am doing wrong? I already added the bin folder, PHP and mySQL root to my PATH yet typing cake on the console does nothing, not even a error code.

Adding to path as ;C:\wamp\www\cake\bin

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it like this:

```
 cd \wamp\www\cake
 bin\cake
```

To try to fix your problem type PATH in your console to see if bake was added.
If you haven't reboot you can run

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\CmdShortcuts
```

Or simply reboot and try again after adding it to PATH.

Check this:

[Update Windows Path](http://dustindavis.me/update-windows-path-without-rebooting/)

[Install Cakephp Console Windows](http://nurelm.com/running-cakephp-command-line-tools-in-windows/)

Comment: Indeed, it was a problem path, I had a different PHP path to the one wamp used. xD

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too,  when I started on cakephp, I really pain in the *** , anyway, this is the correct path

```
C:\wamp\www\cake\lib\Cake\Console;
```

That keeps working for me .